# Payload data with aligned unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++20

I have `unique_ptr<T>` which is always aligned to 4096 - means the lowest 12bits of the pointer value are always equal to 0. My intension is to store a byte of payload data / metadata "in within the pointer itself". I mean to create a class which will have a move converting constructor like:

```
template<typename T>
struct PayloadPtr {
    /* ... */
    PayloadPTr( unique_ptr<T> ptr ) noexcept { ... }
    /* ... */
};
```

which will 'sink' the `unique_ptr<T>` and let it store as member but reusing the lowest 12bits to store the byte variable... The overall layout is important as given by the HW.

```
{
    uint32_t payload : 12;
    uint32_t pointer : 20;
}
```

The whole 32bit value can be read as pointer masking out the payload, the payload can be read out masking the highest 20bits... Important stuff is the T's constructor/destructor is not called during the storage within the `PayloadPtr`, just like regular `unique_ptr` member variable storage.

How to achieve such behavior? To use union having unique_ptr as one member while having the payload as other? Or to store is as plain data (e.g. `uintptr_t`) and reinterpret the data in getters/setters?

What would be the recommended way to implement that? Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: The union approach has undefined behavior (and forces you to write custom special member functions anyway); the uintptr_t approach doesn’t.  If you care about that (which people don’t, always, at this hardware-specific level), that answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create something similar to `unique_ptr` but storing the pointer as a [`std::uintptr_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) and cast and filter out the payload when needed.

Here's an outline what it could look like:

```cpp
#ifndef __cpp_aligned_new
#error "Requires Dynamic memory allocation for over-aligned data (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r4.html)"
#else

#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class PayloadPtr {
public:
    static_assert(alignof(T) % 0x1000 == 0, "must be aligned to a multiple of 0x1000");

    // construct from a T*
    PayloadPtr(T* t) : data(reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(t)) {}

    // take over ownershipt from a unique_ptr
    PayloadPtr(std::unique_ptr<T>&& o) : PayloadPtr(o.release()) {}

    // rule of 5
    PayloadPtr(const PayloadPtr&) = delete;
    PayloadPtr(PayloadPtr&& o) noexcept : data(std::exchange(o.data, 0)) {}
    PayloadPtr& operator=(const PayloadPtr&) = delete;
    PayloadPtr& operator=(PayloadPtr&& o) noexcept {
        std::swap(data, o.data);
        return *this;
    }
    ~PayloadPtr() { delete get(); }

    T* get() const { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(data & ~0xFFFULL); }
    T* release() { T* rv = get(); data = 0; return rv; }

    // dereferencing 
    T& operator*() const { return *get(); }
    T* operator->() const { return get(); }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return get() != nullptr; }

    void reset(T* o = nullptr) noexcept {
        delete get();
        data = reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(o);
    }

    void set_payload(std::uint16_t p) { data = (data & ~0xFFFULL) | (p & 0xFFF); }
    std::uint16_t get_payload() const { return data & 0xFFF; }

private:
    std::uintptr_t data;
};

#endif
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4T6vch)

Comment: @DavisHerring I now replaced the `static_assert` with a plain `#error`. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Come to think of it, outside the template the `static_assert` would be fine, but this looks cleaner.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah, I agree!

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Is it possible to return the payload by reference, not by a copy? In general I have implemented the payload as a class having private members of appropriate size but I need the conversion to Payload class reference in `get_payload()`. But there is the masking within, etc... Something like:
`class Payload { ... };`
`Payload & get_payload( void ) { return ( data & 0xFFF ) } /* Probably incorrect */`

Comment: @MartinKopecký Hmm, if the payload is going to be of class type I'm afraid you'll be restricted to payload sizes as multiples of 8, so a 12 bit payload won't work. Otherwise, you could make the payload type a template parameter. Returning a reference to the payload would be risky since writing to it requires the bit-manipulating stuff.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Maybe the option would be to add the payload as template type and check the bit width at compile time, maybe using a concept or static assert and then, once the checks are passed it might be safe to simply reinterpret the uintptr integral value to the payload type and return by reference... do you think it might work? The remaining question is to check the bit width of the payload...

Comment: You could make it a template but you can't make a type 12 bits long, so it'll only be useful for 8 bit and 16 bit types. Depending on your needs, perhaps a proxy object could be used? [example](https://godbolt.org/z/c81TbP)